# SbtWeb not found when building Scala project with sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to use https://github.com/dispalt/sbt-reactjs plugin in my project. There is an instruction in README to enable plugin `SbtWeb`. I did it like this in my `project/build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
   .settings(
     name := "fooapp",
     version := "0.1",
     scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
   )
   .enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

My `project/plugins.sbt` looks like this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Releases Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
)

addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.6.8")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-web" % "1.2.0")
```

Although everything seems right, I am getting this error when building in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/><pre>
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
/fooapp/project/build.sbt:7: error: not found: value SbtWeb
.enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.</pre>
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am using sbt 0.13.16 set via `build.properties`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in `project/build.sbt` should be in `./build.sbt` (the root of the project). Read sbt documentation about [project structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Directories.html#sbt+build+definition+files).

```
build.sbt
project/
  build.properties
  plugins.sbt
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I also had to remove `.sbt/` from my homedir to force refresh solving other problems and that was it!